# glewInit is undefined but glewExperimental is not

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw, glew

When I compile my code using GLFW and GLEW, glewInit() is an

```
    undefined reference to '_imp_glewInit@0'
```

The curious part, is that it has no problem with the glewExperimental token directly above there. (And if I compile having glewInit() commented out, it will compile successfully and run)

My overall question is, why is glewInit() undefined while changing glewExperimental to true is not; and how do I fix this issue.

My MinGW compiler call:

```
    C:\MinGW\bin\c++.exe -x c++ -o "%cd%\aeonsplice.exe" -static "main.cpp" -Wl,glew32.dll,glfw.dll
```

Where I call glewInit():

```
    glewExperimental = true; // this checks out as fine (I don't have glewExperimental declared anywhere)
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) // this is where it breaks
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW, exiting.\n" );
        aeonAPITerminate(); // This calls glfwTerminate()
        return false;
    }
```

If more information is needed, i'll edit it in by request. And yes, I did search and find the 20+ questions about glewInit() not working, but none of them matched my problem.

Comment: Does it really matter why one is visible and the other is not? It's not going to actually *fix* your real problem (ie: the undefined external issue).

Comment: Yes, as it signifies that part of glew is being properly included while whatever part contains glewInit is not.

Comment: It is relevant information, but not important for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mingw compiler you have to link **glew32s.lib** not **glew32.lib** and it must be at the first on the list of all linkers.

Comment: How would I do that exactly? Would I need to edit how I call c++.exe, or something in my source code? (I never touch glew32.lib outside of including it in mingw/libs)

Comment: You have to define "#define GLEW_STATIC" at the top of the source file and While calling mingw compiler link glew32s.lib not glew32.lin.

Comment: Adding #define GLEW_STATIC to the top of my source file had no apparent change, and I never include glew32.lib, I include glew32.dll (attempting to include glew32s.lib or glew32.lib results in a not found on the file unless I add it to the working directory, in which case it throws undefined references for a slew of functions, most of them '_imp_wglGetProcAddress@4' repeated in different locations)

Comment: Are you using any IDE? If not then show me all command used to compile the project. One thing I didn't understand what you are linking while compiling project. glew32.dll are not for including they are used at runtime not compile time, they must be in system directories. They aren't paly any role while compiling program. During compilation you have to link the library files glew32s.lib, libglfw.a,libopengl32.a.

Comment: I'm not using an IDE, i'm compiling using MinGW directly with the c++.exe supplied by default. The command I used is in the main post, and I do not use any other commands when compiling. 


glew32.dll and glfw.dll must be linked at compile time so that it knows where it pulls the information from, or at least that's my understanding of it. glfw seems perfectly fine running without me declaring explicitly for it to use libglfw.a.

Comment: I finally caved and just used code::blocks to compile my project. adding glew32s.lib and a few other .lib's to the linker got it to compile perfectly.

Comment: @Athix It's a bit of a late response, but you don't link dynamically linked libraries at compile time.  Strictly speaking, you don't link ANYTHING at compile time.  You link things at link time (compile THEN link).  However, dynamically linked libraries aren't even linked at link time.  They're linked at runtime.  That is why they are specified as "dynamically linked."  Static libraries are more or less just object files archived in a separate file to be linked into the executable at link time.